# Clear content of a range if cell contains a specific text

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

I want to make a macro that clears the content of the cells in the **blue border** (~40.000 Rows) when the cells in the **red border** (column AX) contain the text "NoBO" (=No Backorder) without losing the formulas in the columns AP:AX.

```
Sub clear_ranges()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim clearRng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")

For x = 6 To ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If (ws.Range("AX6" & x).Value = "NoBO") Then
        If clearRng Is Nothing Then
            Set clearRng = ws.Range("B6" & x & ":" & "AN6" & x)
        Else
            Set clearRng = Application.Union(clearRng, ws.Range("B6" & x & ":" & "AN6" & x))
        End If
    End If
Next x
clearRng.Clear
End Sub
```

And for some reason:

```
For x = 6 To ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

gives me a error "Overflow". After searching I know what this error means but I can't find a solution for this.

**tl;dr - I want to delete the range B6:B##### (till last row) to AN6:AN####*(till last row) if cell AX##### containts NoBO**

Comment: x Is an `Integer` and can only hold a value of up to 32,767 so if your data goes beyond that row it _overflows_ the max value of x. As Gary's answer states - change it to a `Long` which is more efficient anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It is too easy to get an overflow using `Integer`.  Replace:

```
Dim x As Integer
```

with:

```
Dim x As Long
```

Comment: @Bluesector What happened when you changed `X` from `Integer` to `Long`, as recommended by this response?

Comment: `clearRng.Clear` (end of the code) gives me an error now... im a little bit confused i thought it was only an overflow. - Object variable or With block variable not set

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub clear_ranges() 

Dim ws As Worksheet 
Dim x As Integer 
Dim clearRng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")

For x = 6 To ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If ws.Range("AX" & x).Value = "NoBO" Then
        ws.Range("B" & x & ":" & "AN" & x).Clear
    End If
Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I think the `Union` function can only store up to 30 ranges so it might not suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are Deleting Rows it's the Best to use a For Each Loop or start from the bottom of the column and work up.

```
'Loop through cells A6:Axxx and delete cells that contain an "x."
   For Each c In Range("AX6:A" & ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
       If c.Value2 = "NoBo" Then

             Set clearRng = ws.Range("B" & c.Row & ":" & "AN" & c.Row)

       End If
       clearRng.Clear
   Next
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub clear_ranges()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
With ws
    With .Range("B5:AX" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) 'take all data
        .AutoFilter Field:=49, Criteria1:="NoBO" 'filter to keep only rows with "NoBO" in column "AX" (which is the 49th column from column "B"
        With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1) 'offset from headers
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1)) > 0 Then Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), ws.Columns("B:AN")).ClearContents 'clear cells in columns "B:AN" of filtered rows
        End With
        .AutoFilter 'remove autofilter
    End With
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `.AutoFilter Field:=48, Criteria1:="NoBO"`autofilter method of range class failed

Answer (score 0):

You can try

Assuming that there are no blank cells in AX Column

```
Sub clr_cell()

For i = 6 To ActiveSheet.Range("AX6", ActiveSheet.Range("AX6").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
'counts the no. of rows in AX and loops through all

If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 50).Value = "NoBo" Then

ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 40)).ClearContents
'clears range B to AN

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

I tested this on 40k rows and it worked fine. It takes a while to execute due to the no. of rows maybe.